# echo a multidimensional array in php with variables

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the data from a multidimensional array key in php.
The array structure is like this :

```
Array


( [status] => 1     [embeds] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [embed] => <IFRAME SRC="XXXXXXXX.ZZZ" FRAMEBORDER="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SCROLLING="NO" WIDTH="620" HEIGHT="360"></IFRAME>
                [link] => http://XXXXXXXXXXX.ZZZZ
                [language] => ENG
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [embed] => <iframe src="http://www.XXXXXXX.ZZZZ" width="620" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                [link] => http://www.XXXXXXX.ZZZZZ
                [language] => ENG
            ) ... ... ... ...


    ))
```

The $auto_incrementing_value starts from 1 to as many as there are. so if I want to echo only 1 data and $auto_incrementing_value = 1, I can do `echo $ret['embeds'][$auto_incrementing_value]['link'];`
What I want to do is echo all the "link" value from all the arrays.

I tried this code but it does not work :

```
$codes = 1;
foreach ($ret as $key => $rets){
echo $ret['embeds'][$codes]['link'];
$codes++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sure is some whacky syntax you've got going on there. You're using a `foreach` loop like a `while` loop that is written like a `for` loop.

Try:

```
foreach ($ret['embeds'] as $embed){
  echo $embed['link'];
}
```

Or:

```
for( $i=1; $i<=count($ret['embeds']); $i++ ) {
  echo $ret['embeds'][$i]['link'];
}
```

Or if you want to get *saucy*:

```
$i=0;
while($i<=count($ret['embeds'])) {
  echo $ret['embeds'][$i]['link'];
  $i++;
}
```

### edit

@MarkBaker raises a valid point about calling `count()` [or really any function] in the loop condition. If the function's return will be static during the entire course of the loop [ie: the number of elements in the array doesn't change] then it's best to do:

```
$count = count($ret['embeds'];
for( $i=1; $i<=$count; $i++ ) {
  echo $ret['embeds'][$i]['link'];
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can go backwards:

```
for( $i=count($ret['embeds'])-1; $i>=0; $i-- ) {
  echo $ret['embeds'][$i]['link'];
}
```

Comment: Was going to add to my answer to show the `for` loop, but you beat me to it.

Comment: thank you! Your solution in working great too.  But, witch one is better (speed, errors ...), the foreach loop or the for loop.

Comment: @user2650060 these loops are all more or less equivalent, the differences are all too small to worry about even if the loop runs a billion iterations.

Comment: Any loop that executes count($ret['embeds']) every iteration isn't a well written loop because that is adding a performance overhead

Comment: @MarkBaker true. It's a lazy way to write a loop and should be avoided for arrays larger than what you can count without having to take off your shoes. But I'm *super* lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply iterate over the `embeds` array:

```
foreach($ret['embeds'] as $embed) {
    echo $embed['link'];
}
```

Comment: thanks alot! It working!  I was complicating things but the solution was simple!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an index variable if you're using `foreach`, that's what `foreach` does automatically. You just have to give it the correct array that you want to iterate over.

```
foreach ($ret['embeds'] as $rets) {
    echo $rets['link'];
}
```

Comment: thank you!  It working great .  Also, thank you for explaining!  I was complicating things too much!

Answer (score 0):

PHP >= 5.5.0

```
foreach(array_column($ret['embeds'], 'link') as $link) {
    echo $link, PHP_EOL;
}
```

just to demonstrate one of the newest features in PHP